# adaptar tamaño de las imágenes depende de la resolución de la pantalla android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Estoy creando una aplicación para android en la que tienes que escoger una imagen que sea igual a una que esta arriba, el problema es que al usarla en dispositivos con diferente resolución de pantalla las imágenes no cambian de tamaño y se ponen unas encima de otras haciendo imposible el elegir una.

Se que tal vez es una pegunta muy básica pero, ¿cómo podría hacer que las imágenes se hicieran mas grandes o mas pequeñas dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla del dispositivo?

Os dejo aquí el código:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:onClick="dah"
        android:maxWidth="10dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/exemple16"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="41dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/opcio116"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:maxWidth="10dp"
            android:onClick="nooooooooooooooo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/opcio116"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/opcio216"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:maxWidth="10dp"
            android:onClick="nooooooooooooooo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/opcio216"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/opcio116"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/opcio116" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/opcio316"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:maxWidth="10dp"
            android:onClick="noooooooooooooo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/opcio316"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/opcio416"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:maxWidth="10dp"
            android:onClick="nooooooooooooooo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/opcio416"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/opcio316"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/opcio316" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/opcio516"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:maxWidth="10dp"
            android:onClick="siiiiiiiiiiiiiii"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/opcio516"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: has probado a utilizar un scrollview como contenedor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te aconsejo que le eches un vistazo a la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html?hl=es-419) de Android, ahí te da consejos y una serie de pautas para gestionar varios tamaños de pantalla, por otro lado tienes diferentes formas de solucionar este problema.

### **Primera solución:**

Puedes crearte diferentes tamaños de las imágenes dependiendo de los diferentes tamaños de pantalla:

- **ldpi** (baja) ~120 dpi
- **mdpi** (media) ~160 dpi
- **hdpi** (alta) ~240 dpi
- **xhdpi** (extraalta) ~320 dpi
- **xxhdpi** (extra extraalta) ~480 dpi
- **xxxhdpi** (extra extra extraalta) ~640 dpi

Para ello te deberás crear diferentes carpetas drawable una para cada tamaño de pantalla de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y añadir las imágenes en la carpeta correspondiente según su tamaño, las imágenes deberán tener el mismo nombre en todas las carpetas.

### **Segunda solución:**

Otra solución posible sería la de crear un archivo dimens.xml para cada tamaño de pantalla en los que se definirá el tamaño de la imagen a utilizar dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla.

Para ello se deberán crear diferentes carpetas values como en la primera solución (una por cada tamaño) y dentro de cada una de estas carpetas se crearía un archivo xml llamado **dimens.xml**.

Cada uno de estos archivo xml tendrá la siguiente estructura:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Tamanyos para las imagenes . -->
    <dimen name="width_ima">200dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="height_ima">150dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

En la que dependiendo del tamaño de la pantalla pondremos un valor u otro, luego deberías modificar tu layout para que utilizara estos valores, para ello bastaría modificar los valores de  `android:layout_width` y  `android:layout_height` de la siguiente forma:

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/opcio116"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/width_ima"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/height_ima"
            android:maxWidth="10dp"
            android:onClick="nooooooooooooooo"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/opcio116"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

---

Creo que con una de estas soluciones y siguiendo la documentación de Android podrás solventar tu problema sin muchos inconvenientes. Espero te resulte útil.